# How to extract duplicates while using scrapy link extractor?

Tags: python, scrapy, rules

I'm trying to extract multiple product urls present on category pages. For the same i want to get multiple product urls against the category page url but as one product can be present on various category page, the scrapy get it filtered out. How to prevent that as dont filter = True don't work here? Also, is there a way that scrapy do not checks for response.status of a extracted url and just yields it out.

```
import scrapy
import csv
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from scrapy.spider import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider


class ExtractSpider(CrawlSpider):
    s = []
    with open('C:\\Users\\Vishal\\Desktop\\kk.csv') as f:
        csv_read = csv.reader(f)
        next(csv_read)
        for line in csv_read:
            s.append(line[0])
    name = 'Extract'
    allowed_domains = ["abyexample.com"]
    start_urls = s
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('https://abyexample/product')), callback="parse_link", follow=False)]

    def parse_link(self, response):
        yield {
        "main":response.request.headers.get('referer'),"response":response.url}
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand why do you want to extract the same product url from different categories? That means you are doing the same request twice and that's what scrapy is trying to avoid here.

Comment: I'm trying to make a tree map to store in category database..

Comment: do you need to really hit the site (do the request)? or only "see" that the links exist in the category?

Comment: actually i need to hit the category pages and then extract the product urls from there. thats it ! (Even if they do exist in other category url). My way around right now is look in for respective div id and extract the href but I'm looking for a better methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `unique=False` to [`LinkExtractor`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor).

Answer (score -2):

You can extract duplicates by converting your final link list to a `set()`.

Something like: `set([0,1,1,2,1,3,5])` will result in `{0,1,2,3,5}`, removing duplicate values.

Hope that helps!

Comment: But, I think the scrapy will filter out the duplicate url during the callback to "parse_link". How will I create a set then?